# Data scraping and I get this problem: We're sorry but viewer-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am attempting to scrape https://coworking.routesgrow.com/ .
When attempting to scrape with beautiful soup and normal requests library it wouldn't work. I switched to using selenium and beautiful soup and still the same thing happens and now I recieve this message.
"We're sorry but viewer-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue."

This is my code:

```
#import requests
import xlsxwriter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

page = 1

url = f"https://coworking.routesgrow.com/?page={page}"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
# req = requests.get(url, headers={
# "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

I have attempted several fixes but not on them seem to work. Am I missing or doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you tried switching to a different webdriver or a different version of the same one?

Comment: @AlessandroTogni I tried switching but I thankfully fixed the issue, I had to sleep before retrieving the html for a couple seconds after loading the url. Thanks for the help!